# Lambda Function with axios timing out after the first call

Tags: aws-lambda, async-await, axios, aws-api-gateway

My lambda function is timing out after the first call. For the first time it is invoke it is successful but when you invoke it, it keeps on timing out. Once it times out it works again. I am assuming because the lambda has restarted itself. Is there a memory leak with axios that is why it is timing out?

```js
const users = require('./services/users');
let response;
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event) => {
  try {
    const result = await users.saveData('Smith', 'John')
    const response = {
      'isBase64Encoded': true | false,
      'statusCode': 200,
      'body': JSON.stringify(result)
    };
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    return {
      'isBase64Encoded': true | false,
      'statusCode': 200,
      'body': JSON.stringify(
        {'message': 'error msg'}
      );
    }
  }
};
```

Below is my users module:

```js
const axios = require('axios')
const FormData = require('form-data');
const data = new FormData();
exports.saveData = async (lastName, firstName) => {
  try {
    data.append('lastName', lastName);
    data.append('firstName', firstName);
  } catch (error) {
    throw Error(error);
  }
  const url = 'https://sample.com/users';
  const config = {
    method: 'post',
    url,
    data: data
  };
  try {
    const result = await axios(config);
    return result;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error('An Error Occurred');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A common issue is that by default waits for the event loop to be empty before finishing execution. See https://dev.to/dvddpl/event-loops-and-idle-connections-why-is-my-lambda-not-returning-and-then-timing-out-2oo7

So try changing your code from:

```js
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event) => {
  try {
```

To:

```js
exports.lambdaHandler = async (event, context) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  try {
```

This way, Lambda will finish executing your code even if the event loop is not empty.